# Trouble installing Angular cli

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, terminal

Im trying to install the angular cli using terminal but i keep getting this error

```
- 
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall access
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR!  { Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR!   stack: 'Error: EACCES: permission denied, access \'/usr/local/lib/node_modules\'',
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules' }
npm ERR! 
**npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
➜  ~**
```

I am using my admin account so i am not sure why it is not working, also i have installed node.js just fine without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your application has package.json. If not then run

```
npm init
```

If package.json exists try running

```
npm i
```

and then run

```
npm i -g @angular/cli
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `--allow-root` flag

`sudo npm install @angular/cli -g --allow-root`